# SQL Query to extract nesting from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in which references are made from one row to another. So basically something like this:

```
ID | Name | ParentId
1  | Root | 
2  | Top  |  
3  | Sub1 | 1
4  | Sub2 | 2
```

The third column [ParentId] denotes the parent of the current row.
My question is how do I get this nesting from the table using an SQL query.
The result I would like to see from the query is

```
ID | Name | ParentName
1  | Root | NULL
2  | Top  | NULL
3  | Sub1 | Root
4  | Sub2 | Top
```

It might seem trivial as it is just replacing the id of the third column by the name of the item but I can't seem to figure it out.
Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 3):

for a single level  you could use a left join on the same table

```
select a.id, a.name, b.name 
from my_table a  
left join my_table b on b.parentId = a.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t2.name as parentName
from  table t1
left join  table t2
on t2.id = t1.parentId
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query will help you to achieve your aim:

```
SELECT
    t1.Id,
    t1.Name,
    (SELECT t2.Name FROM MyTable t2 WHERE t2.Id = t1.ParentId) ParentName 
FROM
    MyTable t1
```

If there is a lot of records in the table, by creating an index on the `ParentId` column you can run the above query faster than the `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Fiddle: **[hierarchyid example fiddles](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c29ab/1)**

I decided to take on a slightly different approach to answering this question, using the `hierarchyid` datatype that is supported natively inside of SQL server. 
`hierarchyid` was created to specifically handle record selection/query capabilities for nested relationships, and once you get used to some of the minor annoyances that come with the datatype (such as inline queries/subqueries which are often needed to arrive at the actual id value for a record), its actually pretty slick.

I created a SQL fiddle showing step by step how to use the data-type for an example nested relationship of:

```
/Category One
    /Subcategory 1
        /Subcategory 1.1
        /Subcategory 1.2
        /Subcategory 1.3
    /Subcategory 2
    /Subcategory 3
        /Subcategory 3.1
            /Subcategory 3.1.1
    /Subcategory 4
/Category Two
    /Subcategory 1
```

*NB: the tsql is rewritten and annotated MSDN example code, which was actually quite poorly made imo. I have rewritten and presented it in such a way that I found it much easier to wrap my head around.*

Answer (score 0):

All proposed solution work fine for the posted question. In my "real" situation the table is far more complicated and has already many APPLY statements (specific SQL Server, I guess) so I ended up using the "Outer Apply" variant of posted Join statement:

    `With a AS (
       SELECT id, name from Nesting 
     )

    SELECT id, name, ParentName from a 
     OUTER APPLY (
      SELECT name as ParentName from Nesting n where n.parentid = a.id

  ) AS FOO`

Thank you all so much!