# Recursive Query using to columns to two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, sql-server-2014

I have a system where I have documents linked recursively and I need to create a query that allows me to detect the source document.

I've already been able to implement the same using a Store Procedure with a While but the performance is terrible, since I have to treat approximately 1 million records. Any suggestions on how to implement this recursion query/SP?

In the exemple below I find the document O - 12345 and I need to find the origin document (A - 29503). All my origin documents starts with the DocumentType = A.

```
DocumentType    CodDocument DocumentTypeOrigin  CodDocumentOrigin 
O               12345       E                   32456
E               32456       P                   98472
P               98472       A                   29503
A               29503
```

I would like to get my output like (Edited):

```
DocumentType    CodDocument DocumentTypeOrigin  CodDocumentOrigin FinalDocumentTypeOrigin   FinalCodDocumentOrigin 
O               12345       E                   32456             A             29503       
E               32456       P                   98472             A             29503       
P               98472       A                   29503             A             29503       
A               29503                                             A             29503
```

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: So, what is your expected output going to be here?

Comment: NOTE: Recursive queries aren't generally better or worse than using While or Cursors.  Especially for single lookups (as opposed to bulk queries and DML).

Comment: A well defined cursor is usually faster than a while loop

Comment: @Larnu, I have edited my question to had my expected result. Essentially what I need is to had in each document the document that start this recursive rows.

Comment: This might be of interest to you; this is very different approach to the normal rCTE: [Hierachies on Steroids](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Hierarchy/94040/).

Comment: @RBarryYoung, I have approximately 1 million rows to treat. So my problem is essentially performance based. Treat this number of rows takes to much time. I am trying to find a better way to solve my problem.

Comment: Is there a mistake in your sample data? The 'E' document refers to an origin document of type 'P' whose code is 98472, but the only 'P' document in the data set has a code of 445656.

Comment: @Joe Farrell you are absolutely right.. I correct my mistake

Comment: “Better” includes performance.

Comment: @Larnu I am looking into the link you send me... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a recursive CTE you could do something like:

```
WITH RECURSIVE docSearch AS
(
    --Starting point
    SELECT
        DocumentType as starting_doctype, 
        CODDocument as starting_coddoc,
        DocumentType as child_doctype, 
        CODDocument as child_coddoc,
        DocumentTypeOrigin as parent_doctype,
        CODDocumentTypeOrigin as parent_coddoc,
        1 as level
    FROM yourtable
    WHERE documenttype = 'O' and CodDocument = '12345'

    UNION ALL

    --Recursive SQL (refers back to the the CTE that we are currently in    
    SELECT
        docSearch.starting_doctype,
        docSearch.starting_coddoc,
        docSearch.parent_doctype as child_doctype,
        docSearch.parent_coddoc as child_coddoc,
        DocumentTypeOrigin as parent_doctype,
        CODDocumentTypeOrigin as parent_coddoc,
        level + 1 as level
    FROM
        docSearch
        INNER JOIN yourTable 
            ON docSearch.parent_doctype = yourTable.DocumentType
                AND docSearch.parent_coddoc = yourTable.CodDocument
    WHERE level < 20 --prevent cycling/endless loops
)
--Now select from the CTE for the max docSearch
SELECT * FROM docSearch WHERE level = (SELECT max(level) FROM docSearch);
```

There's no guarantee this will be quicker, but... you might find that you want to remove that WHERE clause in the top SELECT statement to build this table out for every `DocType` and `CodDocument` if you are doing this search often. Then just write the results out to a new table and do all of your SELECTING off of that.

Comment: this works perfectly for one case... But If I comment the WHERE statment (WHERE documenttype = 'O' and CodDocument = '12345') I will omit several documents because I do not know the number of levels haded in each document.

Comment: If you omit the WHERE clause then just do a SELECT * on the recursive CTE in the final select. You'll have to tweak that thing to get what you want out of the recursive results. Something like `SELECT CASE WHEN level = max(level) OVER (PARTITION BY DocumentType, CodDocument) THEN 'DeepestLevel' END ....`  Then just keep `DeepestLevel`.

Comment: Thanks... The query return more than 3 million rows in less than 9 minutes... I had a cross apply in the final statment to get the max level..

Comment: SELECT * FROM docSearch doc WITH (NOLOCK) 
CROSS APPLY 
  (SELECT MAX(level) maxlevel
   FROM docSearch doc1 WITH (NOLOCK)
   WHERE doc1.starting_doctype = doc.starting_doctype AND doc1.starting_coddoc = doc.starting_coddoc
   ) QRY
WHERE doc.level = QRY.maxlevel

Answer (score 1):

For all the documents to be returned I would suggest using a temporary table to hold the results. Then in a loop update the FinalDocumentTypeOrigin and FinalCodDocumentOrigin fields for every record at once going one level up at a time. Terminate the loop when no records are updated or some limit of levels is reached. Only have to loop 1 more times than the max levels of linking.

Comment: The ideia is to create a temporary table to minimize the work but my source table do not have timestamp so I have to process a huge number of rows

Answer (score 1):

[I have a short writeup on another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49835950/814564) asking about nested relationships that shows how to use the `hierarchyid` datatype to populate the datatype, and then query these types of nested relationships.